# Buttons placed incorrectly in a bootstrap masonry

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a masonry image display with bootstrap 4. When an image is hovered on, a ''favorite'' button should appear on top of it. I am able to place the buttons correctly in other projects, but with this masonry all of the buttons appear in the same spot in the middle of the page, and not on top of the relevant image.

Here is my masonry code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="masonry">
        @foreach (var image in Model)
        {
            <div class="item">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Favorite</button>
                </div>
                <img src="~/images/thumbnails/@image.Name" class="img-fluid" />
            </div>
        }
     </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS for masonry:

```
#masonry {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1em;    
}


@media(min-width: 40em) {
    #masonry {
        column-count: 4;
        column-gap: 1em;
    }
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.item img {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.item:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.item:hover .overlay {
   opacity: 1;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a long time, with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you added **position: absolute;** on your **.overlay** class without adding **position: relative;** on your **.item** class.

```
.item {
    position: relative; // add this
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this. The problem is that then the button is placed under the image, and is never visible, with hover or without. But it is really there. Edit: your solution worked, thanks for help. I didn't realize I had to place the overlay class after the image.

Comment: That's also a thing but you could also add "z-index: 1;" on the .overlay class that will prioritized the visibility of the item.